# How to include Data Table from R package (DT) into another HTML file

Tags: javascript, html, r, package, dt

I generated a data table using R package **DT** as follows,

```
library(DT)
load.this <- "DT"
data <- as.matrix(read.table("/path/to/file/name.txt", header = TRUE, fill = TRUE))
table <- datatable(data, filter = 'top',options = list(columnDefs = list(list(targets = c(1, 3), searchable = FALSE)),pageLength = 10))
```

MY aim is to embed the above table in another HTML file, but I am not sure how to do it even after a few try with *escape* argument from the [manual](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DT/DT.pdf).

How can I include the table in a HTML tag, for instance,

```
       <html>
       <body>
<h1> Table from DT package</h1>

    Table comes here

      </body>
      </html>
```

Comment: search about `knitr`, if you use R studio you can try `File > new file >  RMarkdown...` and take it from there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hi you can save it as a `htmlwidget`

```
library(DT)

iris_DT <- datatable(iris)

saveWidget(iris_DT, "iris_DT.html", selfcontained = TRUE, libdir = NULL,
           background = "white", knitrOptions = list())
```

then include it in an iframe in your mail html document

Comment: Thanks for your time and it is exactly what I was looking for@s.brunel